# OpenCSV does not write all records

Tags: java, opencsv

I have written a method in Java for updating a text file delimited by tab. I'm using the opencsv library. First I'm reading in the existing file, then I change the values of some columns and then I overwrite the file. I'm running Windows 7. The problem is now that not everything gets written to the file. Even if I don't change any value and just overwrite the file, not all records are written.

My code is the following. What is wrong with it?

```
 private void csvWrite(int[] boundary, String filename, int answerCount) {
        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        List<String[]> csvBody = null;
        try {
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(PATH + FILE),'\t');
            csvBody = csvReader.readAll();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Search for the file
        int count = 0;
        for (String[] str : csvBody) {
            if (str[0].equals(filename)) {
                // found
                csvBody.get(count)[POS_START_INDEX+answerCount-2] = Arrays.toString(boundary);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }

        try {
            csvReader.close();
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(PATH + FILE),'\t');
            writer.writeAll(csvBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: @ pruntlar Yes without success

Comment: First off write to a different file.   Once writing begins a single error causes you to lose everything that has not been written.  To me that explains what is happening even though you are not saying an Exception is being thrown.

Comment: Second off if there is an error reading print a message and exit.  Don't open up the file you just had problems reading and start writing what it was able to read to it (which is potentially what the above code will do).   Third (for giggles) move the reader close into the read try instead of the write try, especially since now you are exiting on any read error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same issue. For me, it was because I was not properly closing all the readers and writers. 
Got resolved after implementing autocloseable:

```
    private File writeToTempFile(File file) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = new File("/var/tmp/newcsv.csv");
    tempFile.createNewFile();
    try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReader).withSkipLines(4).build();
    FileWriter outputFileWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputFileWriter, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);){
        writer.writeAll(csvReader.readAll());
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return tempFile;
}
```